# Search for a cross-reference

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

In the LyX editor, how can I search for a cross-reference for a certain figure, e.g., search for all places where I reference fig:abc?

My current workaround is to delete the reference. Then, when I open the references table, I see it as "BROKEN: fig:abc" and can go to them one by one. This is quite inconvenient. Is there a better way?

Comment: By references table, do you mean View --> Outline pane, then select Labels and references? All cross references are listed there also before you delete the figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select *View --> Outline pane*, and then select *Labels and references* from the drop down in that pane. That will give you a list of all labels, and each label can be expanded by clicking the small arrow next to it, to show a list of all references to that label.

[image]

[image]